# Where did idea.sh get installed?

Tags: android

I used "umake android" to install Android Studio.  During installation, it warned me of some ibus error I would need to work around.  One way to work around the error is to edit the idea.sh file to add export XMODIFIERS="".  But I can't find that file anywhere.  Where did it get installed?   (I didn't care where the install went, so I accepted the default).

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to list the location or locations of all files named "idea.sh":

```
 sudo find / -name idea.sh
```